# Replacing an entire sentence when a phrase is found

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a JavaScript regular expression that will look in a sentence for a phrase, like "seem to be new" and if it finds  that phase it replaces the entire sentence with "seem". So all the sentences below would be replaced by "seem"

> How do I get rid of the "You seem to be new" message?
>   How do I get kill the "You seem to be new" message?
>   How do I stop the "You seem to be new" message from appearing?

Comment: Are you planning to look through a paragraph of several sentences and picking out and replacing sentences that contain this phrase? Or are sentences coming in independently? Are they each on newlines? My answer should work either way but could be made more flexible depending on the answer to these questions.

Comment: I probably should have provided this information at first instead of after three answers have already been posted, but here's a little more. I have a help system on my page with a "What is your question?" field were people put in ordinary English. I "normalize" the raw input to key "tokens" using a string of RegEx expressions and present the topic to them that matches the most tokens. The three example sentences above are things they might ask (any one, not all) if they're sick of the newbie message. I'm looking for the best way to recognize that's what they're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var str = 'How do I get rid of the "You seem to be new" message? How do I get kill the "You seem to be new" message? How do I stop the "You seem to be new" message from appearing?'
str = str.replace(/[^?!.]*You seem to be new[^?!.]*[?!.]/g,"seem");
console.log(str); // "seemseemseem"
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a8BZA/)

Also, so you can see what happens if I throw in a string that doesn't match:

```
var str = 'How do I get rid of the "You seem to be new" message? How do I get kill the "You seem to be new" message? This sentence doesn\'t seem to contain your phrase. How do I stop the "You seem to be new" message from appearing?'
str = str.replace(/[^?!.]*You seem to be new[^?!.]*[?!.]/g,"seem");
console.log(str); //seemseem This sentence doesn't seem to contain your phrase.seem
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a8BZA/1/)

If you want to replace the sentence but keep the same punctuation:

```
var str = 'How do I get rid of the "You seem to be new" message? How do I get kill the "You seem to be new" message? This sentence doesn\'t seem to contain your phrase. How do I stop the "You seem to be new" message from appearing?'
str = str.replace(/[^?!.]*You seem to be new[^?!.]*([?!.])/g," seem$1");
console.log(str); // seem? seem? This sentence doesn't seem to contain your phrase. seem?
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a8BZA/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function like so:

```
var newString = (
            'How do I get rid of the "You seem to be new" message?'
          + ' How do I get kill the "You seem to be new" message?'
          + ' How do I stop the "You seem to be new" message from appearing?'
    ).replace(/You seem to be new/g, "seem");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LwFxA/)

Comment: The OP wants to the replace `the entire sentence with "seem"` if there is a match within that sentence.

Comment: That's exactly what it does. I threw in a jsfiddle

Comment: All I see is the match itself getting replaced rather than the entire sentence that contains that match.

Comment: thing is, it actually returns a new string so the original one, if it was in a var, is actually not changed

Comment: That's always the case with string operations, but the OP seems to want any sentence that contains a certain phrase to be replaced (the "entire sentence") in that newly created string.

Comment: I offered a solution: the replace method which he can use where he wants. I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using regexp is to use `indexOf`

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/bQAUz/)

```
var str = 'How do I get rid of the "You seem to be new" message?\n\
How do I get kill the "You seem to be new" message?\n\
How do I stop the "You seem to be new" message from appearing?';

var lines          = str.split('\n')  ,
    search_string  = 'seem to be new' ,
    replace_string = 'seem'           ;

for ( var i=0,n=lines.length; i<n; i++ )
   if ( lines[i].indexOf(search_string) > -1 )
      lines[i] = replace_string ;

alert('original message: \n' + str + '\n\nnew message: \n' + lines.join('\n'));
```

Comment: overkill? or actually more efficient than the string.replace method?

Comment: This is also dependent on having newlines between every sentence that is a possible match.

Comment: @JeroenIngelbrecht `String.replace` is most likely the optimized better solution, but `indexOf` is pretty efficient.  I imagine it depends on the length of the string.  I'd use the regex for simplicity.

Comment: @JeroenIngelbrecht Looking at [some tests](http://jsperf.com/regexp-indexof-perf/35) the performance of dynamic regex is slower than `indexOf`

Comment: @smerny: not necessarily.  You could just as easily break your lines like `str.split('. ')` or actually use regex there (eg `str.split(/\n/)`).  If the sentences are in their own elements, then obviously you don't need to split at all, you just select those dom textNodes.

Comment: By "this" I meant the answer posted.

Comment: @smerny:yeah, there are tradeoffs and regex is simpler and may be better still (we still don't know his input format), if you already had the `indexOf` method, and it was one line, you could do a replace/split combo (eg `str.replace(/([?!.])([\s\w\d])/g,"$1\n$2").split('\n')`).  The best answer ultimately comes down to the OP knowing his input.  For instance if the input has wraparound sentences, then your answer is definitely best, but he would have to turn on the single-line mode for the regex.

Comment: I'm just looking at a single sentence that was entered into an <input> field and I think I can solve this, after reading all your comments, with RegEx. What I was missing is that I have to represent the entire sentence in the first term of replace() if I want to replace the entire sentence. So that means using .* before and after the phrase I'm looking for.

Comment: @Steve actually if that's your case, then `indexOf` is probably a better use.  `str=document.getElementById('inputid').value;  if(str.indexOf('seem to be new')>-1)str='seem';`